# Python Pandas: Repeat the column name based on the value in a cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'A': [100, 100, 100, 102, 102],
                    'B': [1, 2, 3, 0, 0],'C': [0, 2, 1, 0, 0],'D': [0, 0, 4, 1, 0]
                   })
print(dfx)

     A  B  C  D
0  100  1  0  0
1  100  2  2  0
2  100  3  1  4
3  102  0  0  1
4  102  0  0  0
```

From this dataframe, I can get all the columns which have values > 0 and put it in a list. This gives the list of unique values:

```
cols = dfx[['B', 'C', 'D']].columns
dfx['list_of_cols'] = dfx[['B', 'C', 'D']].apply(lambda x: x > 0, raw=True).apply(lambda x: list(cols[x.values]), axis=1)
print(dfx)

     A  B  C  D list_of_cols
0  100  1  0  0          [B]
1  100  2  2  0       [B, C]
2  100  3  1  4    [B, C, D]
3  102  0  0  1          [D]
4  102  0  0  0           []
```

But I want a the column name to repeat as many times as the value present in the cell.
The output I am looking for is like:

```
     A  B  C  D   list_of_cols_1            list_of_cols_2
0  100  1  0  0            [1xB]                       [B]
1  100  2  2  0       [2xB, 2xC]              [B, B, C, C]
2  100  3  1  4  [3xB, 1xC, 4xD]  [B, B, B, C, D, D, D, D]
3  102  0  0  1            [1xD]                       [D]
4  102  0  0  0               []                        []
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You expect `list_of_cols_1` too?

Comment: `dfx.iloc[:, 1:].dot(dfx.columns[1:]).apply(list)`

Comment: @yatu, yes, I'm looking for both list_of_cols_1 and list_of_cols_2

Comment: For `list_of_cols_1` try `dfx.iloc[:,1:].astype(str).add('X' + dfx.columns[1:]).agg(lambda x: [i for i in x if not i.startswith('0')],axis=1)`

Comment: One more approach: `dfx.iloc[:,1:].astype(str).add('X' + dfx.columns[1:]+',').replace(r'^0X.*','', regex=True).sum(1).str.split(',').str[:-1] `

Comment: Thanks Ch3steR and user3483203! Both solutions worked. The only problem with user3483203 solution was it took a a few minutes to process a 9000 x 5000 dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `dot`

```
s=df.loc[:,'B':]
df['New Col']=s.dot(s.columns+',').str.split(',').str[:-1]

Out[70]: 
0                         [B]
1                [B, B, C, C]
2    [B, B, B, C, D, D, D, D]
3                         [D]
4                          []
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Accepted your answer as this was the best performing. It took only a couple of seconds for a dataframe of size like 9000 x 5000.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'A': [100, 100, 100, 102, 102],
                    'B': [1, 2, 3, 0, 0],'C': [0, 2, 1, 0, 0],'D': [0, 0, 4, 1, 0]
                   })
print(dfx)

cols = dfx.columns[1:]
list_of_cols1 = [[] for _ in dfx[cols[0]]]
list_of_cols2 = [[] for _ in dfx[cols[0]]]
for x in cols:
    for i, j in enumerate(dfx[x]):
        if j > 0:
            list_of_cols1[i].append(f"{j}x{x}")
            list_of_cols2[i].extend([x]*j)
dfx['list_of_cols1'] = list_of_cols1
dfx['list_of_cols2'] = list_of_cols2
print(dfx)
```